# jQuery hide only working on Chrome Mac and IE, not Chrome PC or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a small function that I wrote to hide a submenu on a wordpress site that uses FoundationPress as a template and unfortunately I've discovered that it doesn't work on Chrome PC or FF. I initially used toggle to hide it but switched to .hide() and then even setting it to .css("display","none") but the problem still persists on the PC side.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button)').click(function() { 
        $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").hide();
    });
    $('.top-bar-section ul li').hover(function() {
        if($("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "none")){
           $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
})
```

What should happen is the user navigates to a section of the site and then uses the menu at the top to jump down to each section. So here: http://development.maclynutility.com/littlefriends/childrens-services/
if you use the menu to navigate anywhere within the current section (children's services) the menu stays active on a PC using Chrome or FF but hides on a Mac or IE. I need it to hide all the time and work like it does on IE or Mac Chrome. Thanks for any help.

Comment: first thing I would check is if $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown") is actually finding anything

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the hover function and not the selector in the click function. The submenu properly hides when I comment out the second hover function but I'm using that to show the menu again if the user goes back to that.

I can see that once the page loads the display property switches back to block from none like it's supposed to but on the mac it stays hidden and actually shows on the pc despite the property being set to block. Is .hover() the proper thing to use there?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because it is not able to find the

```
li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown
```

Make sure what you are targetting.

Comment: I'm curious why it works on some browsers and not others. Forgive me but this is the first time I've encountered a problem like this. How do I check for something like this when it doesn't seem to actually show an error in the console? I might not be looking in the right place though.

Comment: You need to inspect the different computed styles in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "none")){
  $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "block");
}
```

should be:

```
if($("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display") === "none"){
  $("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "block");
}
```

since `$("li.active ul.sub-menu.dropdown").css("display", "none")` will always hide and return the selected dom elements, which are "truthy", and therefore the if body will be executed, showing the dropdown.

However, since it will either display if it's hidden, or do nothing if it's displayed, that function will essentially do nothing differently than if you completely omitted the if statement. Did you intend for it to toggle? Or maybe to show while hovering but hide afterwards?

Comment: The intention there is to show the dropdown after the hovers on it and it's hidden by the first function, which is why I put the if statement inside of a hover triggered by the active menu class. 

Trouble is that it's displaying inconsistently on Chrome, even though the display is set to block it's not displaying on the Mac or IE.

Comment: When does the "active" class get added to the li? Within the hover function, you can use $(this) to get a jQuery object containing the li being hovered over. So maybe you're looking for $(this).find("ul.sub-menu.dropdown").show();

Comment: It's possible but I can't seem to get that to work no matter what I do. I'm lost on why the hove function would counteract the click function even though I'm not hovering over anything.